# I have a chat application but so far I'm not saving the messages to the database. Which of the 2 ways is better?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Right now I have a table called `servers` which contains all the servers. Every server has chat rooms whose names and chat history are saved in a JSON column called `rooms`. The column contains an array of room objects like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'General',
        history: []
    },
    {
        name: 'RandomRoomName',
        history: []
    }
]
```

Right now, whenever a user sends a message, I just push it into the history of the respective room on the server side, however, I don't actually save it in the database so whenever I restart the server, I lose all the history. Now my question is what is the better way of handling this?

1. Whenever a user sends a message, I get the rooms of the server, push the message into the correct room's history and UPDATE the database with the updated objects.

or

2. I rework the database by removing the JSON rooms column, creating a table called `rooms` and another one called `messages`, then creating the respective relationships/associations between the tables

Honestly, both implementations feel a bit weird and not really optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need multiple tables. Jamming stuff into a JSON column is not sustainable and will have *lots* of race condition issues. As the number of messages grows, the expense of re-writing grows as well, making race conditions more likely. This leads into a death spiral where the whole system will melt down under load.

Option 2 is the only realistic way to go. That's the *relational form* you're looking for. The cost of insertion will grow relatively slowly over time and is usually easily handled up to the billions of records before index sizes get too big to fit in memory.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling the JSON alternative wasn't the best. Your explanation cleared things up.

Comment: It will work only under very light load, but after that all bets are off. Hope you can come up with a clean schema for the second option, but it sounds like you're on the right track there.